# Javascript and CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, flot, css-animations

I have site with infinite animating (sliding) background and dynamically updating charts (flot.js). Charts are updating every 200ms, background is sliding via CSS animation (infinite translate3d). Trouble is performance on Android: when chart is redrawing, css animation is stopping for several milliseconds, so it looks like game with 8-10 fps :) Is there any tricks, which can solve this problem?

Comment: It could depend on the image size of your background image. Is it particularly large?

Comment: No, it's 400x200 repeated on full screen picture.

Comment: This is the site: http://cbr.flights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using setInterval to animate the charts every 200ms try using 
window.requestAnimationFrame() in browsers which can support it. The function allows the browser to decide the best time to continue the animation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.requestAnimationFrame